# in cloudfront distribution setting, how can I add multiple alternate domain name(CNAMEs)

Tags: amazon-cloudfront

I planned to my website upload to S3 and deploy with AWS Cloudfront.
And I need to use https connection so i got free domain, 
and also got certification with ACM(AWS Certificate Manager).

I want to mydomain.com and *.mydomain.com(www.mydomain.com) both connect to my website(S3)
when I entered just `mydomain.com` to Alternate Domain name blank, it works well

but, when I tried to add `*.mydomain.com` or `wwww.mydomain.com` to blank like that,
it can't

[image]
I got the error, how can i approach to my purpose?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1** :

You can use either example.com and www.example.com in CNAMEs box.

**Option 2** :

You can directly use *.example.com it will cover all domain excluding example.com.In this case you can create CloudFront one for example.com and one for *.example.com

Reference document :

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/multiple-domains-https-cloudfront/

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/wildcard-support-for-amazon-cloudfront/

Comment: Thanks for your comment.
As a result, It was caused by just a little typo.
I used Route 53. In record set, *.mydomain.com is not exist.
There is *.mydoamin.com(example) laughing at me X(